# 3 axis magnetometer issue in one axis

Tags: breadboard, magnetics, interference, magnetometer

I have several 3-axis magnetometers mounted on breadboards, and they all read correctly in the x and z directions.

The Y direction is very strange; when turned to read `0`, then turned 90 degrees counter clockwise, it reads 0 again. Then the values gradually get larger, peaking at about SE.

What could cause this behaviour?

I thought I had determined the breadboard itself was magnetic but I can't reproduce that.

Comment: I was going to say some magnetic material nearby.  Can you add some leads and move the sensor around?

Comment: Same issue with leads.  If it was something nearby I would expect it to affect every axis. Thought it could be the breadboard because that was stationary relative to the board.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to get it off the bread board?  How sensitive is it?  Nickel is magnetic ... though Nickel plating is thin.

Comment: Yep. It's on 10" leads now and same behaviour.

Comment: It definetly isn't something in the area, when tipping the magnetometer on it's side the Z axis works as expected, and the Y (now Z) shows grossly different numbers when facing up vs facing down.

Comment: What type of magnetometer... I'm ready for a link.  (fluxgate?)

Comment: http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Defense_Brochures-documents/HMC5883L_3-Axis_Digital_Compass_IC.pdf HMC5883L on a breakout board

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what the issue was, but found a better firmware that works much better, and even on the breadboard.

It calibrates the compass before using it, that's the only significant difference I see.

https://github.com/helscream/HMC5883L_Header_Arduino_Auto_calibration